# Changing ec2 instance type, any side effect?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

Hello there i am trying to upgrade ec2 micro instance to small instance.
I am going to upgrade it with [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-resize.html).

But i assigned elastic ip, lot of alarms, load balancer and mounted s3 on it. I knew that elastic ip will lost but i want to know what about others. Alarms, load balancer, mounts. Are they will be ok?

Comment: After upgrade my server responding 503 on browser. There is rails project running on apache2 with passenger.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful with your code.

I had once changed to a 32-bit instance and had problems. In my code I was typecasting the facebook ids to int. So in a 64-bit it was fine. But when I downgraded, this resulted in wrong FB ids.

In your case its an upgrade. So you shouldn't be facing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

No side effects as such. If you are in production, you can point your elastic ip to machine to display "maintenance messages" and re-associate the elastic the resized machine later.

Also be careful about your data on the machine, if you were using instance store, you may want to take a image of the your instance etc. Its much easier with EBS store backed instances. The steps mentioned are quite clear so just follow them carefully.